# How my App can read the group feed/posts on a group of a test user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-group

According to the [Facebook Groups API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api), my Facebook App can read the feed of a group only if an admin of that group installs it on the group:

> By installing your app on a group, a group admin can grant your app access to group content, such as posts, photos, and videos, and allow you to publish content to the group on behalf of the admin.

I have a Facebook App with test users. On one of the test users, I've created a group with some posts. Using the API token of this test user, I can see the group calling the `/me/groups` [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/).

The problem is that I still can't see the posts on the group through the `/{group-id}/feed` [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed). As the docs said, the admin of the group needs to install the app on the group. But when I go to the the *Edit Group Settings* option of the group, and click on *Add Apps*, I can't find my app on that list, and can't install it on the group.

So, how do I configure my App to make it appear on the *Browse Apps for This Group* list of the group of the test user? Or there is another way to read a group feed in order to submit my App to Facebook Review?

Comment: See "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304018/facebook-api-how-to-add-application-to-group-in-developer-mode"