# How can I test an app that uses Facebook Groups API?

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am developing a website that needs to fetch posts from public Facebook groups.
I have created an app in Facebook which is currently in development mode. My role is an "Admin".

At this stage I'm interested in testing the functionality and I have learned that, in development mode, I can fetch posts from groups were I am the group admin ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304018/facebook-api-how-to-add-application-to-group-in-developer-mode)). I created a public group for testing purposes and I am trying to access my posts using this endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/{group-id}/feed?limit=1&access_token={app-id}|{app-secret}
```

As I understand, this should be sufficient as long as I am admin of both the app and group but I receive this OAuthException:

```
To use 'Groups API', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It appears your answer is in the error message. You need to see how you get it approved by Facebook.

Comment: The error message I got would be expected if I was trying to access a group where I was not the admin. The app review is a process required by facebook for an app to "go live" which is not what I want. I want to stay in development mode and test.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't matter what mode you're in. The error is right in front of you. Contact Facebook.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/group/feed#readperms says you need to use a user access token. You are trying to use your app access token.

Comment: That is probably it. So there is no way to access posts on a public group only using an app access token?