# FB posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and permission with user token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I am trying to post to my group by a business app type facebook but getting below error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthorizationException: (#200) 
If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \
and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \
sufficient administrative permission
```

I already ask permission when login( i am using facebook-php-sdk and facebook graph api v2.10):

```
  $permissions = ['email','publish_to_groups' ];
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('mydomain/fb-callback.php', $permissions);
```

I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken and see result of my access_token: Access token info
[image]

So i think problem is my app is not installed in the group. I haved found a similar thread [Facebook API - How to add application to group in developer mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304018/facebook-api-how-to-add-application-to-group-in-developer-mode), but in this answer, it's just say that if i am an admin of both app and group then it will work, but it still return above error. Now i even can't find this app in personal( Settings > Apps) and my group ( My groups > Settings > Apps). Can anyone help me solve this problem, a clue or a tutorial create facebook app post to group please ? Thank you !

---

**Bounty**

To whoever can explain how to post to a Group (not a page) with step by step instructions and screenshots on how to set it up, first in the Graph Explorer followed by **programmatically** - *in either javascript, node, python, c#, powershell or ideally an AWS Lambda*:
[image]

Comment: Hello, did you resolve the problem? I have the same issue. I also can't see the app in my group apps and I am admin of both - the app and the group.

Comment: You can create a test app of your app and test again. It's a clone of your app https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-apps/

Comment: Ok, I created the test app but I still dont see the test app in group apps.

Comment: You don't have to see it. Now you can post to your group by graph api but remember: only you and tester of your test app can see this post

Comment: What the hell of Facebook and their constantly changing API. Did anyone manage to get this to work?

Comment: I have the same problem. Created a new page and a new app. Trying to create a post with an API and getting the same issue but I can't find any valid docs on how to add my created app to the FB page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any solutions to this?