# Facebook API. I can't post to my groups. (#200) Insufficient permission to post to group

Tags: api, facebook, sdk

Facebook API. I can't post to my groups(posts to page works perfect).
It happens when Facebook had some updates with permissions(some was deprecated)
I have error

'**(#200) Insufficient permission to post to group**' If I try to post to groups
I use Facebook SDK for PHP with new permissions.
permissions:

> 

```
        'email',           
        'pages_read_user_content',
        'pages_read_engagement',
        'pages_manage_posts',
        'publish_video',
        'publish_to_groups',
        'groups_access_member_info'
```

I updated my business integration on Facebook page
[image]

But still doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: All the requirements are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#pubperms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm not sure this is the best solution but it works**

It was a solution similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68309391/6284256

`App Installation` is important https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api#app-installation

> Group settings -> click to Apps(below on page) -> enter the name "Application" in the search query used during login ->
> add App

I added screenshots

[image]
[image]

Comment: my app mode is "Live" but in the "Group apps" page I can't find it... any suggestions?

Comment: Same here @AlonSegal my app doesnt shows in the list ;(